# Does a hosted 3rd party JavaScript widget I host on my website give my API access to anyone?

Tags: javascript, http, security, widget

For visitors on my site to be able to use a 3rd party chat widget or be identified by Google Analytics, they must have access to whatever credentials are needed to call those 3rd party APIs from their front end. Does that mean they can easily grab those and programmatically send any requests to those services on my behalf?

Can those services use the domain the HTTP request originated from as a security measure? If I specify that the widget would be hosted on mywebsite.com, isn't it that anyone can fake an HTTP request that looks like it came from that origin?

Finally, is there any reliable security measure for such a scenario or do frontend-only widgets inherently give anyone access to the resource they use?

Comment: _"Can those services use the domain the HTTP request originated from as a security measure?"_ No, you can always use a proxy and rewrite the request. _"If I specify that the widget would be hosted on mywebsite.com, isn't it that anyone can fake an HTTP request that looks like it came from that origin?"_ Yes. Whoever has valid credentials can use the services. You could use MAC or IP filters but as far as I understand that's not possible for your use-case

Comment: When would IP filters be useful? I do want anyone to be able to use the widget when they visit my website so don't want to block out any IP ranges. And as for the attacker, they can always use a VPN to circumvent my filters?

Comment: Therefore I wrote _"You could use MAC or IP filters but as far as I understand **that's not possible for your use-case**"_. To summarize for your use-case: _"Finally, is there any reliable security measure for such a scenario?"_ No. Whoever has valid credentials can use your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any credentials specified on the front-end are available for users. They can use them any way they want (giving they know how), for example, any user can install GA or GTM on their site and use your id to push events to your analytics from their website.